# How to use multiprocessing within for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing, pool

I am attempting to execute multiprocessing within a for loop but the issue is that pool.map seems to be using the last value of the iterable in the for loop for all the iterations.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

args = [1,2]
repeat = 3
output = [0] * len(args)

def myfunc(_):    
    b = 2
    return a +1, b +2

count = 0  
for arg in args:
    
    a = arg
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with Pool(2 ) as p:
             out1,out2  = zip(*p.map(myfunc, range(0, repeat ), chunksize =1))
             temp = [out1,out2 ]
             output[count] = temp
             
    count += 1
```

Output:

```
 [[(3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)], [(3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]]
```

which suggest that myfun is using `a` = 2 for all the iterations in the loop.

Intended output:

```
[[(2, 2, 2), (4, 4, 4)], [(3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]]
```

Note: In reality, `myfunc` is time-consuming simulation with random output ( hence i need to repeat the function multiple times even with the same argument) and it is inherent that I have to initialize a list to store the results

How can I achieve the intended output?

Comment: Move all variables inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'. Only thing outside of it should be the function definition and the imports. When you spawn a subprocess it reinitializes imports and is likely overriding your variable. Also you probably want to use mp.Process within a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables should be inside the `if name == '__main__'`.
Only thing outside of it should be the function definition and the imports.
When you spawn a subprocess it reinitializes imports and is likely overriding your variable. This is most noticeable in Windows, but can still happen in Linux.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def myfunc(a):    
    b = 2
    return a +1, b +2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = [1,2]
    repeat = 3
    output = [0] * len(args)
    count = 0  
    for arg in args:
    
        a = arg
        with Pool(2) as p:
            out1, out2 = zip(*p.map(myfunc, [a]*repeat, chunksize =1))
            temp = [out1,out2]
            output[count] = temp
             
        count += 1

    print(output)
```